# if i click on input field the popup modal opens and after selecting a item it reflect to the clicked input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is on clicking the item in the popup modal, the data-value is reflecting all the input fields

I have tried this code and it works with that but it is also changing others. The data value should reflect on the particular input field only. currently it is changing all the previous and next input fields

```js
    function openmodal(e) {
      //prevent(default);
      //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $(document).on("click", ".hello", function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          e.value=$(this).attr("data-id");
       alert(e.value);
       $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      });
    }
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
    </div>
      
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 1</h3>
          <input id="image1" onclick="openmodal(this);"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 2</h3>
          <input id="image2" onclick="openmodal(this);"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 3</h3>        
          <input id="image3" onclick="openmodal(this);"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <a class="hello" data-id="2">2</p>
      <a class="hello" data-id="3">3</p>
      <a class="hello" data-id="4">4</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function openmodal(input) {
     
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $(".hello").unbind().click(function(event){
    
          $(input).val($(this).attr("data-id"));
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      });
    }
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 1</h3>
          <input id="image1" onclick="return  openmodal(this);"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 2</h3>
          <input id="image2" onclick="return  openmodal(this);"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 3</h3>        
          <input id="image3" onclick="return openmodal(this);"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <a class="hello" data-id="2" >2</p>
            <a class="hello" data-id="3" >3</p>
            <a class="hello" data-id="4" >4</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```